# Pull NT user ID from powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-users, get-wmiobject

```
get-wmiobject -class win32_computersystem -computername c73118 | format-table username
```

Will output something similar to:

```
username
--------
GHS_NTDOMAIN\amacor
```

Is it possible to only output the `amacor` part only?

Comment: there's always the %USERNAME% environment variable, which is just the username component, without domain.

Comment: @MarcB I'm fairly adept with powershell and batch scripting, but I have no idea how to use your comment to get a user name from a remote computer. I think it is safe to assume he is looking at a remote computer since he specifies `-computername` in his `get-wmiobject` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you don't really want FT for this I don't think. Use Select -Expand instead. So doing that we get back the string `GHS_NTDOMAIN\amacor`. Once you have that, you can do .Split("\") to split it into an array of strings, and [-1] to specify the last string in the array. So it would look like:

```
(get-wmiobject -class win32_computersystem -computername c73118 | Select -ExpandProperty username).Split("\")[-1]
```

That will result in:

```
amacor
```

Or if you wanted to be a bit more verbose about it, you can do:

```
$Data = get-wmiobject -class win32_computersystem -computername c73118
$DomainUser = $Data.Username
$UserName = $DomainUser.Split("\")[-1]
```

Then `$UserName` = "amacor"

**Edit:** Updated per Andy Arismendi's excellent suggestion.

Comment: In case there's ever no machine/domain name `[-1]` will work in both cases.

Comment: @AndyArismendi Thank you! I don't know that I have ever iterated into an array from the end like that, but I'm sure I will now that I know that I can. I have updated my answer to utilize your suggestion.

Comment: I had no idea you could start at the end of an array like that. Pretty neat.